# Need to convert the payload to the desired output

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

In the below array there can be multiple objects, and each object can have more than below mentioned key values. I need only the uniqueID and name fields to be displayed.

```
[
      {
        "uniqueID": "1",
        "Name": "Annie",
        "Standard": "3",
        "School" : "ABC School"
      },
      {
        "uniqueID": "2",
        "Name": "Apoo",
        "Standard": "4",
        "School" : "PQR School"
      },
      {
        "uniqueID": "3",
        "Name": "Xavier",
        "Standard": "5",
        "School" : "MNO School"
      }
]
```

Desired output:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "uniqueID": "1",
            "Name": "Annie"
        },
        {
            "uniqueID": "2",
            "Name": "Apoo"
        },
        {
            "uniqueID": "3",
            "Name": "Xavier"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of approaches.

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
errors: payload map {
    uniqueID: $.uniqueID,
    Name: $.Name
}
```

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
errors: payload map {
    ($ - "Standard" - "School")
}
```

Comment: There is a slight disadvantage to the second method using `-` to remove attributes in that you need to explicitly name each of the undesired attributes. If new undesired attributes are likely to be added you need to add each explicitly to the expression.

Comment: hi @Salim the first approach works; Thank you;  However, there are more than 20 key value pairs; the payload I had mentioned is just a sample. So, I couldn't go with second approach.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Salim Khan's answer, another way is to use filterObject() to let only the desired attributes in the output. The advantage is that it is somewhat more generic if other attributes are added or changed.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var allowedKeydNames=["uniqueID", "Name"]
---
{
    errors: payload map (
        $ filterObject ((value, key, index) ->  (allowedKeydNames contains (key as String)))
    )
}
```